# Why is C# is not removing listeners from an Action delegate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates, action

So I've built a very basic event manager for a game in Unity and I'm saving references of Actions in a dictionary like this:

```
public void SubscribeToAction(string actionKey, Action<object> listener)
{
    Action<object> action;
    if(actionList.TryGetValue(actionKey, out action)){
        action += listener;
    }else{
        action += listener;
        actionList.Add(actionKey, action);
    }
}
```

But what happens is that even though I unsubscribe when I exit the scene, I find that calls are being made to old listeners and I'm getting a null exception:

```
public void UnSubscribe(string actionKey, Action<object> listener)
{
    Action<object> action;
    if(actionList.TryGetValue(actionKey, out action)){
        action -= listener;
    }
}
```

The only solution I've found is to clear the entire dictionary when exit the scene and adding the subscriptions again on start() methods.

Comment: Are you using a lambda expression for the listener? E.g. `SubscribeToAction("blah", (obj) => Debug.Log(obj))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`action += listener;` and `action -= listener;` are just changing the local variable `action`.  They're not changing the value in the dictionary.  If you want to change the value in the dictionary you'll need to *set the value in that dictionary*, in your case, to the value of `action`.

Comment: Right! Thanks for your help. That was a pretty stupid mistake.